rsync archive copying files that already exist in destination folder
II have been using a script to rsync files from a foreign repository to a local repository. This script runs on cron every minute ad has been successfully running for months. The goal is to copy and log all new files that are transferred.
recently a new folder in the foreign repo has been placed and all files within that folder are being transferred every iteration despite the file existing in the local repository.it should be noted that this folder contains a significant number of files (more than the other folders)
How can I stop this from happening?
transfer.sh

queueFile='.../queue.txt'
localrepo='.../local/repo'
foreignrepo='.../foreign/repo'

function syncFiles() {
  local dir="$1"
  local dest="$2"
  local queue="$3"
  for file in "$dir"/*
  do
    if [ -d "$file" ]; then
      # These are the different FCT File extensions
      rsync -av "$file"/*key*.csv "$dest" | grep -e 'csv' >>"$queue
      syncFiles "$file" "$localrepo" "$queueFile"
    fi
  done
}

# Only run if queue.txt does not exist to limit ps creation
if [ ! -e "$queueFile" ]; then
    syncFiles "$foreignrepo" "$localrepo"

    echo "Looping through queue lines"
    # Read lines 
    while read line; do
        # echo $line
                ... # this part works
    done < "$queueFile"
    rm "$queueFile"
else
    echo "Queue exists... exiting"
fi

When reading queue.txt I am seeing files being transferred/ logged that already existed in the local repo causing downstream issues in the process
I have read other posts detailing a trailing slash being needed but because this is targeting csv files with names that match a pattern rather than directories this shouldn't be the problem.
I have verified that the local repo has the files prior to each iteration and the local repo has the space needed to transfer the files

You're missing a closing quote after grep -e 'csv' >>"$queue.

Does this problem only occur when you use your script? If you have the same problem when you run rsync by hand on that directory, this isn't a programming problem, it's a question about rsync. And in that case, [unix.se] is the appropriate place to ask (and you can leave out the rest of the script).
